# Meteor: md-autocomplete with reactive helper

Tags: meteor, angular-material, angular-meteor, md-autocomplete

When I use md-autocomplete, the filter is applied to the second last keypress and not to the current one. I tried different options for filtering but I'm stuck and don't know how to integrate my Meteor collection with md-autocomplete.

In my controller component, I have the filter logic implemented like this:

```
this.searchText = '';
this.subscribe('people');

this.helpers({
    people() {
        return People.find({
            name: {
                $regex: `${this.getReactively('searchText')}.*`,
                $options: 'i'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

my template looks this way:

```
<md-autocomplete
    md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
    md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
    md-items="person in ctrl.people"
    md-item-text="person.name"
    md-min-length="0"
    placeholder="Who should be selected?">
  <md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{person.name}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
  <md-not-found>
    Nobody found matching "{{ctrl.searchText}}".
  </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

The filter works beside the problem, that the last key ob my searchText is not applied to filter the list.

Example: I have the people "Till", "Tony" and "Andy" in my collection. when I type "T", nothing is filtered out at all, but the T from Till and Tony is highlighted correctly on my list.
When I type "Ti", Till and Tony stay in the list and Andy is filtered out. The "Ti" of Till is highlighted. So the highlight works as expected, but the filter does not apply to the last letter I typed.

I would be glad for some hints, how to apply my searchText correctly to md-autocomplete. I was searching for my mistake for hours now, without success.

Comment: I've created a working CodePen using your markup *but without Meteor*. Hope it helps in some way - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/AXwGXk?editors=1010#0

Comment: @camden_kid thanks for this. When I not use a reactive meteor helper, it works as expected. So I assume my problem is specific to the combination of meteor reactive sources and md-autocomplete.

Comment: I don't know anything about Meteor but I suspect `this.getReactively` is worth investigating.